# I want to have some data from API file with types define to them and return the data Typescript and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Help me to set the types of this api not for all data only for somedata i think we need to chnage this Promise in return

This is a Api Response

[{id: 1, name: "Buzz", tagline: "A Real Bitter Experience.", first_brewed: "09/2007",…},…]
0: {id: 1, name: "Buzz", tagline: "A Real Bitter Experience.", first_brewed: "09/2007",…}
1: {id: 2, name: "Trashy Blonde", tagline: "You Know You Shouldn't", first_brewed: "04/2008",…}
2: {id: 3, name: "Berliner Weisse With Yuzu - B-Sides", tagline: "Japanese Citrus Berliner Weisse.",…}
3: {id: 4, name: "Pilsen Lager", tagline: "Unleash the Yeast Series.", first_brewed: "09/2013",…}
4: {id: 5, name: "Avery Brown Dredge", tagline: "Bloggers' Imperial Pilsner.", first_brewed: "02/2011",…}
5: {id: 6, name: "Electric India", tagline: "Vibrant Hoppy Saison.", first_brewed: "05/2013",…}
6: {id: 7, name: "AB:12", tagline: "Imperial Black Belgian Ale.", first_brewed: "07/2012",…}
7: {id: 8, name: "Fake Lager", tagline: "Bohemian Pilsner.", first_brewed: "03/2013",…}
8: {id: 9, name: "AB:07", tagline: "Whisky Cask-Aged Scotch Ale.", first_brewed: "03/2010",…}
9: {id: 10, name: "Bramling X", tagline: "Single Hop IPA Series - 2011.", first_brewed: "01/2011",…}

i just need these value/data

```
id: number;
    name: string;
    tagline: string;
    first_brewed: string;
    description: string;
    ingredients: {
      yeast: string;
    };
    image_url: string;
    abv: string;
```

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from "axios";
type Props = {
  post: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    tagline: string;
    first_brewed: string;
    description: string;
    ingredients: {
      yeast: string;
    };
    image_url: string;
    abv: string;
  }[];
};
export const instance : AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}`,
});
type filters={
    beerName: String
    yeast: String
    date: String
    abv: String 
    id: number
    endPage:number
    postPerPage:number
  }
export const getBeersService = async (filters:filters, currentPage:number):Promise<any>=> {
  const { id, beerName, yeast, date, abv, postPerPage } = filters;
  const idQueryString = id ? `&ids=${id}` : "";
  const yeastQueryString = yeast ? `&yeast=${yeast}` : "";
  const beerQueryString = beerName ? `&beer_name=${beerName}` : "";
  const dateQueryString = date ? `&brewed_after=${date}` : "";
  const abvQueryString = abv ? `&abv_gt=${abv}` : "";
  const PerPageQueryString = postPerPage ? `&per_page=${postPerPage}` : "";
  const url = `/beers?page=${currentPage}${PerPageQueryString}${dateQueryString}${abvQueryString}${beerQueryString}${idQueryString}${yeastQueryString}`;
  return await instance.get(url);
};
```